# Gulp not copying files

Tags: gulp, laravel-elixir

I'm trying to copy the font files from the bower install to the public directory.
So I installed MaterializeCSS via bower.

And I have the following in my `.bowerrc`:

```
{
  "directory": "resources/assets/bower"
}
```

and in my `gulpfile.js` is the following:

```
elixir(function (mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss')
       .copy(
        "../assets/bower/materialize/dist/fonts/**",
        'public/fonts'
    );
});
```

the sass is done correctly but my files aren't copied. but in the console it says:

```
[13:52:32] Finished 'sass' after 1.7 s
[13:52:32] Starting 'copy'...
[13:52:32] Finished 'copy' after 3.84 ms
```

anybody knows why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that Elixir does not minify compiled CSS by default. You can however minify it by passing the --production option to gulp:

```
$ gulp --production
```

http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2014/11/11/introducing-laravel-5-elixir/

Comment: Thanks but I'm aware :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly certain that the materialize fonts are in a folder called "font" rather than "fonts". If elixir can't find the target to be copied then it won't copy anything.

Comment: Yes that was the problem, found it. But forgot to post